# ITK filter on different pixelspacing and slicethickness

Tags: itk

Pixel Spacing and Slice Thickness of my 3D data are different, in other words, grid of x/y axis is different from grid of z axis.

Will ITK filters still work on this type of images?

If not, how to make modifications? Maybe use interpolation to generate isotropic images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ITK Images have proper support for such *anisotropic* images. This is controlled by different voxel spacing along Z axis. Read more in description of [`itk::ImageBase`](https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1ImageBase.html).

Comment: Javascript problem with this page, I could not upvote and accept your answer until recently. Assume there is a data structure, and a function based on this data structure, then _anisotropic_ issues should be solved in data structure, rather than in function. Am I understanding corretly??

Comment: There is meta-data which indicates spacing along each axis, and almost all filters (functions) take that into account.